# How to run jenkins.war in background and use cli

Tags: docker, jenkins, war

I am pretty new to Docker. I need to do the following tasks:

- Run Jenkins instance in Docker
- Configure it to auto-install JobDSL plugin on startup

I wrote DockerFile

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD jenkins.war jenkins.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","jenkins.war"]
```

and then I run `docker run ...`
But there is one problem I can't use the console but I have to use the console to install the plugin. I tried to solve this problem using & at the end. It did not help. P.S I can't use the jenkins image

Comment: You might be able to find a `docker run` option to launch containers in the background, or another Docker command to get a shell in a running container.  There's also a [manual path to install Jenkins plugins](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/#advanced-installation) which you could put in a Dockerfile.

Comment: I know about how to launch container in the background. I need to run exactly jenkins.war in background within docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins use a JENKINS_HOME directory where it stores config, jobs and plugins.

One way to achieve what you want is perhaps to set the plugins in this directory before running jenkins.

- If you use the official jenkins image, then perhaps you can use a data volume to store that and run docker to use this data volume: `docker run -V /your/data/volume:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins`
- If you don't want a data volume, and want an image with the plugins, then you can add to you dockerfile something like:

`RUN mkdir -p ~/.jenkins/plugins && \
        cd ~/.jenkins/plugins && \
        wget http://your/plugins/plugins.jpi`

- finally you can mix a little bit both by creating a shell script that check if the plugins directory exist, and if not get the plugin file, then start jenkins. This shell script would be your image entry point.

NOTE: The file you need to download as plugins is the `.jpi` file! not the `.hpi`.

As reference, here an example:

```
FROM java:8
RUN  wget https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/war/2.121.2/jenkins.war && \
    mkdir -p ~/.jenkins/plugins && \
    cd ~/.jenkins/plugins && \
    wget https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/org/jenkins-ci/plugins/job-dsl/1.33/job-dsl-1.33.jpi
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","jenkins.war"]
```

Comment: You need to download the JPI file, not the HPI.